# The nature of truth and logical connectives

Tags: logic, ontology

I think most would agree that:

- P or !P
- !(P and !P)

are always true.

This allows us to have certainty no matter what we're talking about.

Does that make the logical connectives the most fundamental objects of the universe?

I can't think of any other notion that one can appeal to make sense of them. Even proving them requires using them in a meta language. They just seem true by nature.

Comment: No, it makes them not to have anything to do with the universe. They are conventions we use to phrase things and reason about them, conventions of our own making. Hence our certainty about them. They are true not by nature but by design.

Comment: perhaps "objects" is the wrong word, but what I was trying to say is perhaps these conventions are somehow models of structures of reality that is the base of everything?

Comment: It is more plausible that they reflect the structure of our reasoning more than reality. But contrary opinions have been voiced, see [SEP, Is logic neutral about what there is?](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ontology/#LogNeuAboWhaTheL2MeeO2)

Comment: I skimmed it a bit, sounds like a very interesting read. thanks as always!

Comment: You should have a look at : Wittgenstein's Tractatus. An interesting question would be : is cognitive content proportional to certainty? There might be totally vacuous certainties... Wittgenstein claims that the meaning of a proposition consists in its truth conditions. You understand a proposition when you know what would be the case if it were true. You may ask yourself: what will be the case if  " It will rain tomorrow OR it will not rain tomorrow" is true?